# How can I avoid re-initializing a variable when using recursion in c++?

Tags: c++, recursion

So I'm just starting to learn about recursion and I'm confused as to how avoid this problem.  I will write a function that needs to store a variable, like a sum, but I have to declare the variable in the function so every time the recursive call is made the variable gets initialized again.  How can I fix this? I think a helper function of some short but I'm not really sure.

```
int fib_tail(int n)
{    
    int fibResult = 0;
    int x = 0; // used for bottom-up approach
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n > 1 && x <= n) {
        fibResult += fib(x);
    }
    ++x;
    return fib_tail(n);
}
```

Comment: The variable accumulating the result is typically passed in as a parameter.

Comment: My bad for not providing an example. Here's an example of an attempt at making a tail recursive number for Fibonacci.

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you provided your code. However usually you pass whatever you need in and return the result.

An example:

```
int Sum(Node* node)
{
    if (node == 0)
        return 0;
    return node->value + Sum(node->next);
}
```

**Edit**

Here is what I would do in your example:

```
int fib_tail(int n)
{    
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fib_tail(n-1) + fib_tail(n-2);
}
```

Ide one: http://ideone.com/hS2s38

Comment: Why do you have a `current`-variable... this is not needed in any way... you even missed it yourself in your code while calling Sum :D

Comment: Haha, so easy to make simple errors when making an example. Thanks @SkryptX